# Herança em Rails

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, ruby-on-rails, ruby, herança, rails4

Estou começando na área, tenho o seguinte cenário no meu back end feito em rails:
Eu quero implementar uma classe pai:

Equipamentos:
ID PK
Marca
...

E algumas classes filhas

Impressora:
ID_EQUIPAMENTO PK e FK
...

Computadores:
ID_EQUIPAMENTO PK e FK
...

Telefones:
ID_EQUIPAMENTO PK e FK
...

Dentre outas

Mas eu tenho 2 problemas, o primeiro é como definir a chave primária da classe pai para ser a chave primaria das classes filhas.
O outro é como implementar isso no controler e nas rotas.

Estou atolado nisso já faz um tempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse site pode te ajudar, o item 2.5 "[The has_one :through Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association)" parece ser o que você precisa.

->se precisar definir a PK sua **Equipamentos** seria equivalente a **class Document** (apresentada no fim da da seção)

-> se não precisar seria a **class Physician** mesmo.